# Difference between credential file created by java kinit versus that of windows cache

Tags: java, authentication, kerberos

wish to know if the credential file generated by Java's kinit is the same as that created in "cache" or memory when the user logged in.

For example,  using kinit the credential file is by default krb5_[username].

I also have a piece of code that gets the Kerberos ticket from the currently logged in user:

```
public static byte[] getTicket() {
    // defined the realm, kdc etc here
    .....
    try {

        LoginContext lc = new LoginContext("SomeLoginContext"); 
        lc.login();
        Subject signedOnUserSubject = lc.getSubject();          
        Set<Object> privatePrincipalsSet = signedOnUserSubject.getPrivateCredentials();
        if (privatePrincipalsSet != null && privatePrincipalsSet.size() > 0) {
            for (Object privatePrincipal : privatePrincipalsSet) {
                //make sure it is the kerberos ticket
                if (privatePrincipal instanceof KerberosTicket) {
                    KerberosTicket ticket = (KerberosTicket)privatePrincipal;
                    return ticket.getEncoded();  <------- is this correct?
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (LoginException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

    }   

    return null;

}
```

May I know if the internal "format" of the credentials are the same.?
thanks